# Javascript encodeURI not work well with csv

Tags: javascript, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying generate short CSV by the code bellow :

***Source***

```js
const csv_content = `"Hello"þ"World"þ"#"þ"123"`;
const href = 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv_content);
console.log(href);
```

I copy/past the **href value** in my browser and download it.

***Value of href***

```
data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,%22Hello%22%C3%BE%22World%22%C3%BE%22#%22%C3%BE%22123%22
```

I open it in Excel but I can't show any chars after **#** char and the # itself.
If someone can explain me why **encodeURI** and **#** return me this issue, that would be wonderfull !

## SOLUTION

`evolutionxbox` comment resolve this issue, you need use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) instead `encodeURI`

```
// encodes characters such as ?,=,/,&,:
console.log(`?x=${encodeURIComponent('test?')}`);
// expected output: "?x=test%3F"
```

Comment: Because `#` has a specific meaning in URLs. try using `encodeURIComponent` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLUTION

`evolutionxbox` comment resolve this issue, you need use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) instead `encodeURI`

```
// encodes characters such as ?,=,/,&,:
console.log(`?x=${encodeURIComponent('test?')}`);
// expected output: "?x=test%3F"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue actually touches on an important topic, and that is what should be passed in a URL vs what should be passed in the body.

When you get to complex objects, like a csv file, it would be best to use the body to hold this information, as it is much less picky about characters.

Another reason is that the URL is open and unprotected information. If you ever made a csv file that contained sensitive data, anybody in the world can see it. Data in the body (assuming you are using https) is encrypted and not open to all viewers.

---

It is also important to remember the correct uses for `GET`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, `DELETE` and `POST`. When working with sending a file I would be hard pressed to find a good reason to use `GET` as the requestor (if the requestor is the one sending the csv file), the only one of the above where it breaks convention to send data in the body of the request. It is perfectly okay to have data in a `GET` response body though.